# Monitor Azure Application Insight Data Ingestion

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm using Azure Application Insights to collect logs & custom metrics. I'm billed on amount of data ingested. Thus, I want to monitor that value.

Ideally i should be able:

1. See data ingestion statistics for the entire data retention period (90 days);
2. See how much data was ingested today (some delay is okay).

The closest thing i was able to find was a "Data volume trends" chart under "Usage and estimated costs" in the AI resource.

But:

1. That is very rough view (small chart, no way to filter/drill in);
2. It only shows last 30 days;
3. I have no idea how old "today" value is.

Googling around did not yield any useful results. Does anybody have an idea if what i need here is even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Metrics explorer to chart this information. Select "Metrics" and then fill in the below info:

- For "Metric Namespace", select "Log-based metrics"
- For "Metric", select "Data point volume"
- Click "Apply splitting" and select "Telemetry item type"

You can also change the chart to a Bar chart for better readability of this data.

Comment: See [Understand your usage and estimate costs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#understand-your-usage-and-estimate-costs) of the Azure documentation.

Comment: I don't think this is groupped per day, it's groupped per 6 hours, so it doesn't make sense co compare the chart from "Data volume trends" with this one from Metrics explorer

Comment: As @sschmeck points out, the right query is available in the link in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

So, as @JoyA pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498912/7232025), we need to use "Data point volume" metric to collect this kind of data.

As for part 2 of my question (ability to show last 90 days), I found out that by default "Metric chart" on dashboards only allows you to have "Last 30 days". So, the trick is:

1. Create a chart for last 30 days
2. Download your dashboard definition. That will give you a .json file
3. Find "relative": "43200m" value and replace it with "129600m".
4. Save, upload.
5. Voila, you have a chart for last 90 days.